# How to draw an animated rectangle?

Tags: c#

How to draw a rectangle that could move to the edge of the PictureBox and when it reached the edge, it would unfold. And there could be several such rectangles

Here is the code of the class with the Draw function (Pike.cs):

```
using System.Drawing;

namespace course_project
{
    internal class Pike : Fish
    {
        private Point coordinates;
        private Size size = new Size(40, 40);
        private Size speed;

        public Pike(Point data, AquariumForm aquariumForm) : base(Color.Green, aquariumForm)
        {
            Data = data;

            speed = new Size();
        }

        public Pike Next { get; set; }

        public override void Draw(Graphics graphics)
        {
            graphics.FillEllipse(brush, coordinates.X, coordinates.Y, size.Width, size.Height);
        }

        public void UpdateLocation(Rectangle bounds)
        {
            if (!bounds.Contains(coordinates + speed))
            {
                if (coordinates.X + speed.Width < bounds.Left || coordinates.X + speed.Width > bounds.Right - size.Width)
                {
                    speed.Width *= -1;
                }

                if (coordinates.Y + speed.Height < bounds.Top || coordinates.Y + speed.Height > bounds.Bottom - size.Height)
                {
                    speed.Height *= -1;
                }
            }

            coordinates += speed;
        }
    }
}
```

Linked List (PikeFlock.cs):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;

namespace course_project
{
    internal class PikeFlock : IEnumerable<Pike>
    {
        Pike head;
        Pike tail;
        int count;

        public void Add(Point data, AquariumForm aquariumForm)
        {
            Pike pike = new Pike(data, aquariumForm);

            if (head == null)
                head = pike;
            else
                tail.Next = pike;

            tail = pike;

            count++;
        }

        public bool Remove(Point data)
        {
            Pike current = head;
            Pike previous = null;

            while (current != null)
            {
                if (current.Data.Equals(data))
                {
                    if (previous != null)
                    {
                        previous.Next = current.Next;

                        if (current.Next == null)
                        {
                            tail = previous;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        head = head.Next;

                        if (head == null)
                            tail = null;
                    }

                    count--;
                    return true;
                }

                previous = current;
                current = current.Next;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public int Count { get { return count; } }

        public bool IsEmpty { get { return count == 0; } }

        public void Clear()
        {
            head = null;
            tail = null;
            count = 0;
        }

        public bool Contains(Point data)
        {
            Pike current = head;

            while (current != null)
            {
                if (current.Data.Equals(data))
                    return true;

                current = current.Next;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public void AppendFirst(Point data, AquariumForm aquariumForm)
        {
            Pike pike = new Pike(data, aquariumForm)
            {
                Next = head
            };

            head = pike;

            if (count == 0)
            {
                tail = head;
            }

            count++;
        }

        public IEnumerator<Pike> GetEnumerator()
        {
            Pike current = head;

            while (current != null)
            {
                yield return current;
                current = current.Next;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable)this).GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

AquariumForm.cs (The form itself):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace course_project
{
    public partial class AquariumForm : Form
    {
        readonly Aquarium aquarium;

        public AquariumForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DoubleBuffered = true;

            aquarium = new Aquarium(ClientRectangle);
            aquarium_timer.Interval = 100;
            aquarium_timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            aquarium_timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Pike pike in aquarium.pikeFlock)
            {
                pike.UpdateLocation(ClientRectangle);
            }

            foreach (Carp carp in aquarium.carpFlock)
            {
                carp.UpdateLocation(ClientRectangle);
            }

            Invalidate();
        }

        private void Add_carp_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            aquarium.carpFlock.Add(new Point(), this);
        }

        private void Add_pike_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            aquarium.pikeFlock.Add(new Point(), this);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            aquarium.Paint(e.Graphics);
        }
    }
}
```

Aquarium.cs:

```
using System.Drawing;

namespace course_project
{
    internal class Aquarium
    {
        readonly public PikeFlock pikeFlock;
        readonly public CarpFlock carpFlock;
        readonly Color waterColor;

        public Aquarium(Rectangle clientRectangle)
        {
            waterColor = Color.LightSkyBlue;
            pikeFlock = new PikeFlock();
            carpFlock = new CarpFlock();
        }

        public void Paint(Graphics graphics)
        {
            graphics.Clear(waterColor);

            foreach (Pike pike in pikeFlock)
                pike.Draw(graphics);

            foreach (Carp carp in carpFlock)
                carp.Draw(graphics);
        }
    }
}
```

Fish.cs

```
using System.Drawing;

namespace course_project
{
    internal class Fish
    {
        private protected Brush brush;
        private protected AquariumForm aquarium_form;

        public Fish(Color color, AquariumForm aquariumForm)
        {
            aquarium_form = aquariumForm;

            brush = new SolidBrush(color);
        }

        public virtual void Draw(Graphics graphics) { }

        public Point Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Confused just at the point where you need to animate it all. By clicking the button everything is created as it should be, but animation does not work, even I do not know how :(

Comment: For an animation you need a TImer and change the data in its Tick event. Loops won't work as only the rend-result will actually be shown..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post `fish.cs` so without testing I would suggest the following changes:

- Do not use `PictureBox`, it just complicates things if you perform custom animations this way. So instead of extracting the `Graphics` from its assigned `Image` property, which is backed by a `Bitmap` that has the same size as your form (btw. what happens if you resize your form?) simply just use the `Graphics` that is already there when your form is redrawn.
- Unlike `PictureBox`, a `Form` does not use double buffering by default so you might want to set `DoubleBuffered = true` in the form constructor to avoid flickering.
- Override OnPaint in the form and initiate the whole repaint session from there:

```cs
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    aquarium.Paint(e.Graphics); // instead of your Init() method
}
```

- It means you don't need `bitmap`, `graphics` and `aquarium_form` fields in your `Aquarium` class. Instead, you can pass the form's `Graphics` to a `Paint` method:

```cs
// in Aquarium.cs:
public void Paint(Graphics graphics)
{
    // Please note that graphics can have any size now so it works even if you
    // resize the form. Please also note that I treat pikeFlock as a Pike
    // enumeration instead of just coordinates
    g.Clear(waterColor);
    foreach (Pike pike in pikeFlock) // instead of int[] items
        pike.Draw(graphics); // instead of Draw(int[])
}
```

- Your `PikeFlock` is just `IEnumerable`, I would change it to `IEnumerable<Pike>` to make it strongly typed.
- It also means that `PikeFlock.GetEnumerator` should yield `Pike` instances instead of int arrays: `yield return current` instead of `current.Data`
- `Pike` has now `int[]` as coordinates. I would change it to `Point`. And do not pass new random coordinates in every drawing iteration because every fish will just randomly 'teleport' here and there. Instead, maintain the current horizontal and vertical speed.

```cs
// in Pike.cs:
private Point coordinates;
private Size size = new Size(40, 40);

// speed is declared as Size because there is an operator overload for Point + Size
// Do not forget to initialize speed in constructor
private Size speed; 

public override void Draw(Graphics graphics)
{
    // no Refresh is needed because graphics comes from the form's OnPaint now
    graphics.FillEllipse(brush, coordinates.X, coordinates.Y, size.Width, size.Height);
}

public void UpdateLocation(Rectangle bounds)
{
    // if a fish would go out of bounds invert its vertical or horizontal speed
    // TODO: if you shrink the form an excluded fish will never come back
    // because its direction will oscillate until you enlarge the form again.
    if (!bounds.Contains(coordinates + speed))
    {
        if (coordinates.X + speed.Width < bounds.Left
            || coordinates.X + speed.Width > bounds.Right - size.Width)
        {
            speed.Width *= -1;
        }
        if (coordinates.Y + speed.Height < bounds.Top
            || coordinates.Y + speed.Height > bounds.Bottom - size.Height)
        {
            speed.Height *= -1;
        }
    }

    coordinates += speed;
}
```

- Now the only thing is missing is the animation itself. You can add a `Timer` component to the form from the Toolbox.

```cs
// form:
public AquariumForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DoubleBuffered = true;

    // No need to pass the Form anymore. Pass the bounds instead to
    // generate the initial coordinates within the correct range.
    // No Random field is needed here, use one in Aquarium constructor only.
    aquarium = new Aquarium(ClientRectangle);
    timer.Interval = 100;
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    timer.Enabled = true;
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Updating coordinates of all fish. We just pass the current bounds.
    foreach (Pike pike in aquarium.pikeFlock)
        pike.UpdateLocation(ClientRectangle);

    // Invalidating the form's graphics so a repaint will be automatically
    // called after processing the pending events.
    Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Appended Fish.cs

Comment: I did everything according to your instructions, but for some reason there is still no animation. The problem is that there are not only pike but also carp. For Carp.cs also has a linked list (CarpFlock.cs). All of this changed in the same way. The new code attached to the question

Comment: Now you initialize speed with default value (0,0). So maybe the animation is running but all fish have zero speed. Instead use some random value between -5 and 5 or so. And please also note that the newly added fish have also zero coordinates. I suggested to move the `Random` in the `Aquarium` class. And you don't need to pass the form to the flock/fish classes.

Comment: Yes, I really missed that I initialized the speed with a zero value. Thank you very much!